# I published my ASP.NET Core 6 project it published successfully, but when I run .exe file that say ConnectionString cannot be null

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

Here is my code:

Program.cs :

```
using _0_FrameWork;
using _0_FrameWork.FrameWorkApplication;
using _0_FrameWork.Infrastructure;
using AccountManagement.Configuration;
using AccountManagement.Infrastructure;
using Espadana;
using Invoice.Configuration;
using Invoice.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "CSRF-TOKEN");

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ESDb");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(c => c.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IPasswordHasher, PasswordHasher>();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IFileUploader, FileUploader>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthHelper, AuthHelper>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IApplicationManager, ApplicationManager>();

InvoiceBootstrapper.Configure(builder.Services, connectionString);
AccountBootstrapper.Configure(builder.Services, connectionString);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddMvcCore(c => c.EnableEndpointRouting=false);

builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
    {
        o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login");
        o.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Login");
        o.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Login");
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(option =>
{
    option.AddPolicy("Account",
        builder => builder.RequireRole(new List<string> { Roles.Administrator })
    );
    option.AddPolicy("Invoice",
        builder => builder.RequireRole(new List<string> { Roles.UserSystem, Roles.Administrator })
    );
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMvcOptions(option => option.Filters.Add<SecurityPageFilter>())
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(option =>
        {
            option.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Invoice", "Invoice");
            option.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/AccountPages", "Account");
            option.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Index", "Account");
        }
    );

    var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

    app.UseHsts();
}

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    var context = services.GetRequiredService<AccountContext>();
    context.Database.EnsureCreated();
     DbInitializer.Initialize(context);

   var  contextI = services.GetRequiredService<InvoiceContext>();
   contextI.Database.EnsureCreated();
   
}

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMvc();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

`appsettings.Development.json`:

```
{
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ESDb": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ES;User ID=sa;Password =123456"
  }
}
```

Error:

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be
> null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)     at AccountManagement.Configuration.AccountBootstrapper.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(DbContextOptionsBuilder c) in F:\ProjectAsp.net\es1\es15Incomplete\Espadana\Espadana\AccountManagement.Configuration\AccountBootstrapper.cs:line 19     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(IServiceProvider  p, DbContextOptionsBuilder b)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDbContextOptions[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.b__0(IServiceProvider
> p)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope
> scope)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
> serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type
> serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
> provider, Type serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
> provider)    at Program.$(String[] args) in
> F:\ProjectAsp.net\es1\es15Incomplete\Espadana\Espadana\Espadana\Program.cs:line
> 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the environment of the runtime, .net looks for different settings files. So if your environment is `staging`, .net looks for `appsettings.staging.json`. In VS debug mode, the default is `appsettings.development.json`. In your cases the environment of the machine is set to something else.

To fix this issue, you can do one of these

1. change the environment of the machine where you are publishing the exe to development
2. add a file called `appsettings.xxxxxx.json` where 'xxxxxx' is the environment of the machine
3. If you have common connection string for both dev and publish (HIGHLY DISCOURAGED) you can put your connection credentials in `appsettings.json`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0